# Testing editable DT using Shinytest

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to create unit tests for a shiny app I've been working on but can't work out how to input values for an editable DT table.

Example app:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table"), 
  textOutput("mean")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  tableUpdate <- reactiveVal(0)

  table <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10, C = 11:15)

  output$table <- renderDT({table},
    options = list(paging = FALSE, dom = 't'),
    selection = 'none',
    server = FALSE,
    editable = list(target = 'row')
  )

  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    table <<- editData(table, input$table_cell_edit)
    tableUpdate(tableUpdate() + 1)
  })

  output$mean <- renderText({
    tableUpdate()
    paste(mean(table$A), mean(table$B), mean(table$C))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Example test:

```
library(shinytest)

app <- ShinyDriver$new(".")
app$setInputs(table_cell_clicked = list(row = 2, col = 2, value = 7), allowInputNoBinding_ = TRUE)
app$setInputs(table_cell_edit = data.frame(row = 2, col = 0:3, value = "1"), 
              allowInputNoBinding_ = TRUE, priority_ = "event", wait_ = FALSE, values_ = FALSE)
app$takeScreenshot()
app$stop()
rm(app)
```

I've kept this mostly how it came out when I recorded the test, but I've corrected the setInputs values of table_cell_edit and table_cell_clicked (which came out as vectors).

This gives the error:
`Error in sd_getAllValues(self, private, input, output, export) : 
  Unable to fetch all values from server. Is target app running with options(shiny.testmode=TRUE?)`

Running in test mode does not fix the issue.

Comment: Your `app.R`needs tweaking, hasn't successfully managed to edit and store the editted values. Also, do you have to define `table_cell_clicked` in the `app.R` code can't seem to find it there.

Answer (score 0):

While experiencing the same issue, I managed to fix yours.
the mistake was here (when you are trying to update the reactive value):

tableUpdate(tableUpdate() + 1)

instead of ....

tableUpdate(table)

Please find the updated entire code below.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    DTOutput("tabled"),
    textOutput("mean")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    tableUpdate <- reactiveVal(NULL)
    table <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 6:10, C = 11:15)
    output$tabled <- renderDT({table},
                             options = list(paging = FALSE, dom = 't'),
                             selection = 'none',
                             server = TRUE,
                             editable = 'row')
    observeEvent(input$tabled_cell_edit, {
        table<<- editData(table, input$tabled_cell_edit,'tabled')
        tableUpdate(table)
        a<-mean(table$A)
        b<-mean(table$B)
        c<-mean(table$C)
    output$mean <- renderText(paste(a,b,c))
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```